# How to check about my unfiled tax return 15 yrs ago in the US or how to determine if I still have unpaid taxes to pay

Tags: united-states, taxes

I believe I may have some unfiled tax return in the US 15yrs ago. Although I filed for the 1st yr of my employment before and paid my taxes my last remaining months back then I believe I left without filing my taxes due to a family emergency. Tried going to irs.gov and used my old SS number but I couldn't see any option that would allow me to see unpaid taxes on my part. Also considering a tax advocate for help. Pls. advice on how to go about this more efficiently. Thanks in advance.

Btw, I was on H1-B visa before

Comment: Do you have any idea what your income was in that year (1998)?

Comment: hi @JoeTaxPayer, probably it was 4,500 a month which rounds up to 55k/annum. if you can give me an estimate on the compounded interest amount pls do. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statute of limitations doesn't start to run until you file a tax return for the year for which the tax return is due. So, the clock hasn't started yet.

If you were supposed to pay taxes - you're still on the hook, theoretically.

If you were supposed to get a refund, however, the statute of limitations for the claims for refund is either 2 years after the tax was paid, or 3 years after the return was filed, which ever is later. However, since you didn't file the tax return at all - only the 2 years after the tax payment period holds, so refunds are long gone. See [26 U.S. Code § 6511](http://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/26/6511).

That said, I suggest consulting with an experienced tax professional (EA/CPA/Attorney licensed in your State) for a proper advice on what your course of action should be. Do **not** talk to the IRS (including the Tax Advocate service, which is part of the IRS) before you had that consultation.

Comment: thanks @littleadv your answer was helpful but how to view the unpaid amount i.e. some govt website maybe. if its possible can you recommend an EA/CPA/Attorney to me?

Comment: @apache1 you can view your account transcript, you can read my blog article about it here. http://littleadvisor.wordpress.com/2014/01/18/great-new-service-from-the-irs-get-your-account-transcripts-online/

Comment: However keep in mind - the IRS might not even be aware that you owe something at this time. Since you didn't file your return - there's information missing that they don't have. So your account may have zero balance, but if someone asks you "hey, where's your return for year XXXX?" because there's a W2 with income amounts above the filing limits and you didn't file - you'll have to file in full. And then the audit starts...

Comment: great info! thanks a lot for the speedy answer. God bless.